# High CPU usage when sending email, site freezes

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssh, central-processing-unit

I just moved to a new dedicated server and I'm running into the following issue.

I need to email 8000 of my users using the basic PHP mail function - nothing fancy, it's HTML-formatted but it's just text, no images or other content.

On the previous server, which was a VPS with 1/4 of this server's RAM, I could send the emails 2000 at a time with very little lag on the site as a result.

However, on this server even sending 50 emails gets the CPU usage up to about 40% and lags the entire site considerably. Here is a Putty screenshot, I was wondering if someone has an idea what could be wrong here:

[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CCf5.png)

It's a CentOS/Apache dedicated server, 8GB of RAM, and the CPU is:

Intel® Xeon® E3-1230v2 3.3GHz 8MB Cache Turbo Quad Core /8T

It really doesn't look like it should have a problem with such a simple task, right?

Comment: Rate limiting at the gateway? If direct sending, slow DNS server reponses?

Comment: It is strange, on the screenshot I have see that some perl script have used ~40% of cpu and wa is 6,6%, but you have told that you have used a php mail function to send an emails. It's looks like exim use some perl based antispam/antivirus protection system

Answer (score 0):

Is there something in the distribution chain of your mail server ? Is there an new anti-spam, anti-virus ? It can slow down the delivery if there is a lot of mail to be passed. Check in the logs (Postfix ?) to see what demands all this time. Is there a rate limiter too ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to check these things? I've never had to worry about mail before so I don't know where to start.

Comment: What is the mail server in your system ? Postfix ? Exim ? Sendmail ? the logs are usually in /var/log/mail.log

Comment: It's Exim. There is no mail.log, what I see in /var/log is exim_mainlog. I'm adding some of its contents to the question.

Comment: There's also exim_paniclog and exim_rejectlog, and now I see there is a maillog, attributed to cron for some reason.